# Why does docker container persist changes despite restart

Tags: docker, persistence, docker-container, docker-image

I login to `ubuntu` docker container having name `epic_torvalds` using `docker exec` and create a file `/tmp/test.log`

I then wish to persist this change `/tmp/test.log` so I do `docker commit epic_torvalds newlogimage`

Now stopping and starting the containers using `docker container rm -f <containerid>` for both `epic_torvalds` & `newlogimage` shows `/tmp/test.log` even after restarting the docker daemon.

My expectation was that the changes to the container once committed are saved in the newly created container and do not persist in the base image from which it was created.

Only If I delete the image of `epic_torvalds` and recreate the old ubuntu image using `docker run` is when the /tmp/test.log is lost.

Thus, is the changes to a container persisted by default despite restarts without `docker commit`?

Is there is a feature not to persist changes to the container if that happens to be the default behavior?

Comment: The original image base is `ubuntu` which does not contain test log file. `epic_torvalds` is just a container (created from ubuntu base image) and it will persist your changes between restarts.

Comment: Based on your docker commit command, `epic_torvalds` is a container, not an image. The file in epic_torvalds is going to be there for as long as the container exists. Stopping and starting epic_torvalds doesn't kill the container, so the file is still there.

Comment: Please answer how to NOT persist changes to a container upon restarts without recreating or pulling the image? @usuario and Hans Kilian

Comment: If I `docker run --rm ubuntu touch /tmp/test.log`, and then `docker run --rm ubuntu ls /tmp`, I won't see the file.  But if I write a Dockerfile that `RUN /tmp/test.log` and build an image out of that, it should be there (unless a tmpfs gets automatically mounted).  I routinely delete containers after running their single command, and I never run `docker commit` (it produces images that can't be recreated or updated).